# ZipArchive::extractTo without creating subdirectory of zip file's name

Tags: php, zip

I have a zip file called `myzip.zip`.  It contains `/myzip/file1.png` and `/myzip/subdirectory/file2.png`.

I wish to extract it to `/home/me/somedirectory` so I try:

```
$zip->extractTo('/home/me/somedirectory');
```

I now have:

```
/home/me/somedirectory/myzip/file1.png
/home/me/somedirectory/myzip/subdirectory/file2.png
```

But I wanted:

```
/home/me/somedirectory/file1.png
/home/me/somedirectory/subdirectory/file2.png
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Did you look at the [first User Note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php#100802) in the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682491/extract-files-in-a-zip-to-root-of-a-folder).

Comment: @MarkBaker  Yes, I did, but evidently not well enough.  Thank you

Comment: @AedixRhinedale  That posted solution does not all subdirectories in the zip file.

Comment: @MarkBaker That posted solution does not all subdirectories in the zip file.

Comment: In that case, read the second User Note

Comment: @MarkBaker  Now I am really feeling silly.  Let me read and test.  Thanks