# php how to extract zip and keep sub directory without create a root directory?

Tags: php

I have zip file like this

```
my.zip
    hello.json
    map
      test.png
      b.obj
```

use following code to extract

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('my.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

It will create  directory like this

```
/my/destination/dir/
     my
         hello.json
         map
            test.png
            b.obj
```

I'd like to get this result

```
/my/destination/dir/
         hello.json
         map
            test.png
            b.obj
```

how to do this in php？

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102788/ziparchiveextractto-without-creating-subdirectory-of-zip-files-name or you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682491/extract-files-in-a-zip-to-root-of-a-folder

Comment: Take a look at the user examples on https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php

Comment: @infete I looked the links you provide before , none of them solve my problem, my problem  is different as I clarified  in the question.

Comment: @VidyVideni second link should solve the problem.

Comment: @infete, It can not.