# Unzip folder contents to root

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have a zip folder that I want to place into the root of my application. The zip folder and contents looks like this;

```
documents.zip
  - docs/
    - index.html
    - test.txt
```

Using the following code;

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;

$zip->open( $package, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE );

$zip->extractTo( ROOTPATH );
```

The zip folder is unzipped and ends up looking like this;

```
- docs/
  - index.html
  - test.txt
```

However I'd like to place the contents of the `docs` folder in the actual environment root. `ROOTPATH` (the env root, from above) evaluates to `app/public/` so the zip folder contents is currently unzipped to `app/public/docs/`.

How can I move the contents with ZipArchive into the root?

Comment: You _never_ want to enable `php` to write into the file system location that is served by your http server.

Comment: The PHP implementation doesn't seem to have the "junk paths" option, but you can do this from the shell with `unzip -j`.

Comment: You can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682491/extract-files-in-a-zip-to-root-of-a-folder

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php vuser note 1 seems to be what you are asking